# Try to send value 00,01,02 from html>select but in PHP value are 0,1,2

Tags: php, html

I would like to send POST data array from this code

```
<select name="product_type[]" class="form-control">
   <option value="00">ไม่ระบุ</option>
   <option value="01">เฟอร์นิเจอร์</option>
   <option value="02">ไลฟ์สไตล์</option>
   <option value="03">ของตกแต่งบ้าน</option>
   <option value="04">เครื่องประดับ</option>
   <option value="05">แฟชั่น</option>
   <option value="06">อาหาร</option>
   <option value="07">ออกแบบสื่อ (Multimedia, Graphic, Interactive)</option>
</select>
```

Then I display the value like this

```
foreach( $product_name as $key => $n ) { echo $product_name[$key]."<br>"; }
```

but the code display like this

```
1
2
3
4
```

I would like them to display like this

```
01
02
03
04
```

Do you guys have any suggestion or tell me what am I done wrong?

Thanks for an advance

Comment: are you confusing product_type with product_name?

Comment: Sorry sir, it just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$product_name` actually comes from `$_POST['product_type']`, you're just printing the array index and expecting the array value. Since you don't assign keys explicitly they default to consecutive zero-based integers, as in this other example:

```
$product_name = [];
$product_name[] = '00';
$product_name[] = '01';
$product_name[] = '02';
$product_name[] = '03';
$product_name[] = '04';
$product_name[] = '05';
$product_name[] = '06';
$product_name[] = '07';
print_r($product_name);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 02
    [3] => 03
    [4] => 04
    [5] => 05
    [6] => 06
    [7] => 07
)
```

Additionally, in a tag like this:

```
<option value="00">ไม่ระบุ</option>
```

… only the value (`00`) gets sent back to server, not the label (`ไม่ระบุ`). You can't read the latter from `$_POST`.

Comment: Yes sir, of cause. but the things I need is the value in the option tag. it is 00,01,02.... but when I echo it out from my PHP, it just echo 0,1,2,3.....

seems like it doesn't display correctly sir.

Comment: @Christmas I'm unsure of what your comment means. You're apparently just repeating your question so I must be missing something :-?

Comment: Sorry for my poor grammar sir. I dont know how to explain but i just notice at your message about "assign keys explicitly they default to consecutive zero-based integers". So, could you please tell me how to set the value to string not integers?

Comment: Do you mean `<select name="product_type[yellow-kittens]" class="form-control">`? Why do you need to duplicate information you already have?

Comment: because I need it as an ID to define it later sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="product_type[]" class="form-control">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['product_type'])){
$product_type=$_POST['product_type'];

foreach( $product_type as $key => $n ) { echo $product_type[$key]."<br/>"; }
}
?>
```

Comment: if you will pass value as string (which is in my code) then it will be 01 02 03..  (you can convert to int as per you need)

Comment: yes, I had done that but the value still comes with integer not string.